upgrade scankit sdk 2.12.0.301 has crash
07-01 10:07:28.597 30724 30724 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.iflytek.aistudyclient.parentcontrol, PID: 30724
07-01 10:07:28.597 30724 30724 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference
07-01 10:07:28.597 30724 30724 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.huawei.hms.scankit.p.w7.a(Utils.java:280)
07-01 10:07:28.597 30724 30724 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.huawei.hms.scankit.e.onSensorChanged(IRemoteCustomedViewDelegateImpl.java:6)
07-01 10:07:28.597 30724 30724 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(SystemSensorManager.java:981)
07-01 10:07:28.597 30724 30724 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
07-01 10:07:28.597 30724 30724 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
07-01 10:07:28.597 30724 30724 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)
07-01 10:07:28.597 30724 30724 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
07-01 10:07:28.597 30724 30724 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-01 10:07:28.597 30724 30724 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
07-01 10:07:28.597 30724 30724 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
expect huawei engineer to help us to solve this problem
